# How to get the secure signed artifacts from Azure devops pipeline agent

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to develop a azure pipeline for secure signing the binary artifact.

Here is the process:

1. Put the signing tools and binaries in a GitHub repository.
2. User upload the binaries to GitHub repository folder "unsigned" and run the pipeline, pipeline pull the tools and binaries to a pipeline agent(Winserver) and sign the binaries, the signed binaries will be copied to repository folder "signed".
3. Directly download the signed binaries from pipeline agent, or upload signed binaries back to GitHub repository where users can download from.

For step 3:
How to directly download the signed binaries from pipeline agent to a local PC?
What git commands is needed for uploading signed binaries back to GitHub repository? Thanks.

Comment: just git commit & push to the git repo, then clone the repo to your local PC

Comment: @Ming Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Shayki, you can try the following git command in a cmd task.

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git checkout master
git add .
git commit -m "abc"
git push https://{yourPAT}@github.com/xxx/yyy.git
```

Here is a [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855931/push-updates-from-azure-to-github/56865761#56865761) you can refer to.