# Manage API Mangement from central GIT Repo in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-git-deployment

We have multiple teams working on the same Api Management instance, and the current git-based configuration that API Management provides, does not really facilitate a good process for us (with support for code reviews, pull requests, deploys etc.).

Can we use a GIT repository in Azure DevOps to control the configuration instead of having to use the repository provided directly by API Management?

Our primary use cases are:

1. Merge/sync changes from API Management into our central repository
2. Performing changes in a DevOps repo in separate branches, merge the changes to the main branch via pull requests and sync'ing the changes to API Management

Answer (score 0):

We can clone the configuration repository and push changes back- using our familiar Git commands.

You can try to run the following command in cmd task of azure devops pipeline.

```
git clone https://username:password@{name}.scm.azure-api.net/
git add .
git commit -m "abc"
git push
```

Here are the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git) and similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855931/push-updates-from-azure-to-github/56865761?noredirect=1) you can refer to.

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin. I know the GIT-feature of API Management, but that does not enable us to store the configuration in a repository inside of Azure Devops, where we can collaborate via pull requests, pipelines etc. In my eyes, the GIT-feature og APIM is simply another way to store the configuration, but it is not very flexible.