# How to merge on-prem artifacts to master branch?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have an Azure Devops repo that looks for merges into master that contain *.sql files and will initiate a build pipeline that downloads the sql files along with any dependencies to my on-prem agents and iterates over those objects contained within each file(s) to automate script backups from production. The powershell script that runs on-prem creates a BACKUP directory inside my artifact if one does not exist. How can I use git to then push those objects (aka my SQL backups) back into the master branch? One thing I am struggling to wrap my head around is that this build is fired off of a merge into master so if I am also doing another merge from my build agent, is that bad practice to overlap files? To clarify, the initial PR will not contain the BACKUPS directory with my sql backup files, but rather new sql scripts and or modifications submitted by the user.

```
#Only execute build pipeline when merge to master branch contains .sql file additions/modifications
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - '*.sql'


pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: get_changed_files
  pool:
    name: 'DBDevOps_Stage'
  steps:  
  #Pulls down any sql files that have been added or modified along with any dependency files such as .ps1 scripts
   - task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         $targetfolder = "$(Build.StagingDirectory)" + "/"

         write-host "target folder: $(Build.StagingDirectory)"
         
         function CopyFiles{
             param( [string]$source )
         
             $target = $targetfolder + $source
         
             New-Item -Force $target
             copy-item $source $target -Force
         }
         
         $changes = git diff  --name-only --relative --diff-filter=AM HEAD^ HEAD *.sql
         write-host "printing changes variable:"
         $changes
         write-host "Change variable ended."

         if ($changes -is [string]){ CopyFiles $changes  }
         else
         {
             if ($changes -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($change in $changes){ 
                   CopyFiles $change 
                   }
             }
         }

         $PowershellFiles = git ls-files *.ps1
         if ($PowershellFiles -is [string]){ CopyFiles $PowershellFiles  }
         else
         {
             if ($PowershellFiles -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($PowershellFile in $PowershellFiles){ 
                   CopyFiles $PowershellFile
                   }
             }
         }

         $DLLFiles = git ls-files *.dll
         if ($DLLFiles -is [string]){ CopyFiles $PowershellFiles  }
         else
         {
             if ($DLLFiles -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($DLLFile in $DLLFiles){ 
                   CopyFiles $DLLFile
                   }
             }
         }

         $ConfigFiles = git ls-files *Config.csv
         if ($ConfigFiles -is [string]){ CopyFiles $ConfigFiles  }
         else
         {
             if ($ConfigFiles -is [array])
             {       
                 foreach ($ConfigFile in $ConfigFiles){ 
                   CopyFiles $ConfigFile
                   }
             }
         }

   - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
     inputs:
      pathToPublish: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
      artifactName: MyChangedFiles

#Downloads above files/artifacts to the Default Working Directory
#Powershell scripts iterate over files and backup scripts to a BACKUPS directory using SMO
- job: backup_sql_files
  dependsOn: get_changed_files
  pool:
    name: 'DBDevOps_Stage'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
    inputs:
      artifactName: MyChangedFiles
      downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) 
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      #SMODependencyChecker.ps1 must be executed first. This script will then call PowershellBackupSQLScripts.ps1 once the dependencies are loaded.
      filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PowershellScripts/SMODependencyChecker.ps1'
      Arguments: "-FilePath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
```

My repo:

[image]

On-Prem working directory w/ new backup files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [push updates from azure to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855931/push-updates-from-azure-to-github)

But you should be able to skip the part about the PAT ( based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728908/21995792)

Another resource with some examples is Microsoft's git command page for Azure DevOps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Ultimately, I think you'll want to make a script that `git commits` the pipeline's changes to the files `git push`es the files you want to the branch you need.